# Invoking a method of an anonymous class without reflection in java

Tags: java, bdd, dsl, anonymous-inner-class

I want to do something like this

```
static <T> T mine()
{
    return  new Object(){void hello(){}};
}
```

so that I can do this

```
mine().hello();
```

the intend is to do something like this

```
mine.hello().hi().bye();
```

so either I declare classes each with 1 method hello,hi,bye and than return there instances or somehow I could return an anonymous class(with newly defined method) form each method like above. so that I dont have to write lot of classes.

Like it I can do

```
static <T> T tunnel(T t)
    {
        return t;
    }

tunnel(new Object()
        {
            void hello()
            {
                System.out.println("hello");

            }
        }).hello();
```

but its of no use, I want to return anonymous object(created in tunnel itself) from tunnel , instead of returning passed argument

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the builder pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#Java

Comment: Na, I am like looking in some short of BDD type code, like Mockito.doReturn(...).when(...) but problem is I want to have only one method i.e hello() to be called over return of mine() and only hi() to be called on return of hello() so this means I have to declare multiple classes and return instances of them. thats what i want to avoid with anonymous class, if its possible

Comment: Well then it's not possible with anonymous classes, because that is what they are - anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a fluent class. Something like

```
public class MyFluentClass {

   public MyFluentClass methodOne() {
     // do something
     return this;
   }

   public MyFluentClass methodTwo() {
     // do something
     return this;
   }
}
```

And then in your main method:

```
MyFluentClass myFuent = new MyFluentClass();
myFluent.methodOne().methodTwo();
```

Comment: with your approach it fulfills the requirement partially, but flaw is API user may also possibly trigger a method chain this way myFluent.methodTwo()..methodOne() but that is not allowed and thus I have to than create antoher class having only methodTwo() and than return instance of that class from methodOne() of MyFluentClass

Comment: In that case you might take a look at the step-builder-pattern: http://rdafbn.blogspot.nl/2012/07/step-builder-pattern_28.html

Comment: Although not what I was looking for, but still somehow address my problem. Thanks @Ronald